# Recover Tensorflow variables from model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been working with a TF model and I want to restore the model variables. However, these variables were never saved during the Training stage, and I'm wondering if there is a way to recover those from just the model I recreated from just the .h5 weights file.

This is how I'm recovering the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session(config=conf) as sess:
    restored_model = my_custom_model(sess, ...)
    restored_model.load_weights('/path/to/file.h5')
```

The `my_custom_model()` definition initializes variables like this:

```
    # Init vars before training
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    K.set_session(sess)
```

However, during training, the model variables were not saved. Is there a way to get these variables?

Comment: What do you mean "the variables were not saved"? If they weren't saved, they're gone. You cannot magically reconstruct them out of thin air.

Comment: That should be it. I thought I could recover them in some way, but I guess I'll have to train it again then.

Comment: you cannot, when you train a tf model the variables are overwritten at every iteration, you must watch at them during the process if you want to save them